# Align horizontally two spans in the middle of a flexbox

Tags: html, reactjs, css, flexbox

I have a div (flex) containing 2 spans that I want to be aligned like [this](http://prntscr.com/iqjwe0).

What I have now is [this](http://prntscr.com/iqjxf1)

Code:

```
<div className="MemberLinks">
      <div>
        <span className="linkTitle">Schedule of Benefits</span>
        <span>
          <a href="./manifest.json">
            doc.pdf
          </a>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span className="linkTitle">General Exclusions</span>
        <span>
          <a href="./manifest.json">
            doc.pdf
          </a>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.MemberLinks {
margin-top: 1em;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
.linkTitle {
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 .6em 0 0;
}
```

I want to accomplish horizontally alligned spans in the midle of them, so it stays formatted like there was a even space between elements

Comment: You'll need two columns one with `text-align: right;` and one with `text-align: left;`. You can use flexbox or a table for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to use flex to achieve this effect.

What I've done is removed the flex, set the `span`s to have 50% width, then set the `text-align` property to `right` for the first `span`.

```css
.MemberLinks {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.MemberLinks span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0 0.1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.MemberLinks span:first-of-type {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="MemberLinks">
  <div>
    <span class="linkTitle">Schedule of Benefits</span><span>
          <a href="./manifest.json">
            manifestdoc.pdf
          </a>
        </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="linkTitle">General Exclusions</span><span>
          <a href="./manifest.json">
            otherdoc.pdf
          </a>
        </span>
  </div>
</div>
```